# Parsing Unstructured Data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parsing, computer-science

I am working on writing a bookmarklet that will pull information from a site and send it off to a users account to be saved for later usage. This generally includes the problem of taking unstructured information and making it structured. Take for example a hobbyist wants to save a project for later. There are a number of parts that they need to obtain and instructions to follow. On one blog, the writer could refer to the instructions as *directions* or *recipe* or any number of synonyms. One person may list the information with `<li>` tags to order the steps, while another may not.

What are general strategies to turn unstructured data into structured information? Are there other strategies to determine which content is relevant? (i.e. Instapaper or Readability)

Comment: I don't think there are "general strategies" for this. The "general strategy" would probably be to tell them to structure their content. If that is not an option, you should probably get yourself hired at Google and tackle this problem with their backup for the next few decades of your life :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is a good computer science answer to this question, so I have decided to change the approach and have users organize the data as they see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...maybe you could use this in conjunction with Google? Taking a look a head & meta tags is a good idea too. You could also take a listing of how often words are used. Heck, you could even have a popup alert that asks the user to enter data about the page.

Comment: What about in cases where enthusiasts just use WordPress or Blogger and the meta tags are not meaningful?

Comment: @rynmrtn: In that case they probably don't care about their users extracting structured data from their stuff.